# Is there a way to load data into the store only during development?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I would like to add data to the Vuex store when in development mode (i.e. `vue-cli-service serve`), but want to exclude that data when I build the app (i.e. `vue-cli-service build`). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Modes and Environment](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes) you can use the environment variable `process.end.NODE_ENV` to check which environment the Vue application us running in:

> NODE_ENV will be set to "production" in production mode, "test" in
>   test mode, and defaults to "development" otherwise.

You can use these values to conditionally execute or not execute pieces of code such as only dispatching an action that leads to a mutation when in "production" mode:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  this.$store.dispatch('someActionThatLeadsToMuation');
}
```

`process.env.NODE_ENV` can be used effectively anywhere in your @vue/cli project including the store, components, etc. That being said, I just want to make you understand that on it's own, the Vuex store is effectively ephemeral. It doesn't persist data like a database or a file. So whatever you create/read/update/delete in the store in development mode, will absolutely not carry over when you build the application. The data inside the store entirely relies on the actions/mutations you are executing when the application starts/runs in combination with the initial state values specified.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: "the Vuex store is effectively ephemeral" - Thanks. Yes - I only want some data during development for when adjusting the UI.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unsure by your response, does that answer your question? The store is not a database that persists. It's in-memory and entirely populated by actions/mutations you dispatch via your code.